# Python 3.3.3 in shell 'range(6) returns range(6) and needs list(range(6)) to return 1,2,3,4,5,6

Tags: python, list, range

using a Python 2.7... tutorial in shell, typing `range(6)` returns `>>> range(6)` and not the expected sequence. That requires `list(range(6))` which then does return the list. Has this operation of range changed?

Answer (score 4):

[Yes](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists):

> `range()` now behaves like `xrange()` used to behave, except it works with values of arbitrary size. The latter no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you, I used the answer to check further, I am obliged.

Answer (score 0):

on the new python 3.3 and up you have to make a list for Ex :

---

```
    myList = [ ]    # which is empty. 
    for x in range(10):
        myList.append(x-1)
    print(myList)
```